# A metric inducing the topology of pointwise convergence on a bounded subset of $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

> We have $A:=\{x=\{x_{n}\}\in \ell^{2}| \phantom{x} \|x\|\leq 1\}$ Consider the metric $d:A\times A \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ defined by 
>   $$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1/2)^{n}|x_{n}-y_{n}|$$
>   Show that 
>   $$ d(x_{n},y)\rightarrow 0 \phantom{x}\mathrm{as}\phantom{x}n\rightarrow\infty \phantom{x}\Leftrightarrow d(x_{nj}, y_{j})\rightarrow 0 \phantom{x} \mathrm{as} \phantom{x} n\rightarrow\infty \phantom{x} \mathrm{for} \phantom{x} \mathrm{each}  \phantom{x} j \in \mathbb{N}. $$

Question: How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with one direction. Suppose $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $\Omega$, that is each $x_n$ is a sequence $x_n = (x_{n,j})_j$ of real numbers. Suppose $d(x_n, x) \to 0$, for each $j$ we have 
\begin{align*}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}
  \abs{x_{n,j} - x_j} &= 2^j \cdot 2^{-j} \abs{x_{n,j} - x_j}\\ 
       &\le 2^j \cdot \sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k} \abs{x_{n,k} - x_k}\\
       &= 2^j \cdot d(x_n, x)\\
       &\to 0.
\end{align*}So $d$-convergence implies pointwise convergence.

On the other side, suppose $x_{n,j} \to x_j$ holds for each $j$. Note that for any $n,j$ we moreover have 
$$\abs{x_{n,j} - x_j} \le \|x_n\| + \|x\| \le 2 $$
by definition of $\Omega$. Now, given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $J$ such that $\sum_{j=J+1}^\infty 2^{1-k} \le \frac{\epsilon}2$. For $j \le J$ we can choose a $n_j$ such that $\abs{x_{n,j} -x_j} \le \frac{\epsilon}{2J}$ for $n \ge n_j$. Let $N = \max_{j \le J} n_j$, then for $n \ge N$ we have 
\begin{align*}\def\eps{\epsilon}
  d(x_n, x) &= \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j}\abs{x_{n,j} - x_j}\\
            &= \sum_{j=1}^J 2^{-j}\abs{x_{n,j} - x_j} + \sum_{j=J+1}^\infty 2^{-j}\abs{x_{n,j} - x_j} \\
            &\le \sum_{j=1}^J \frac{\eps}{2J} + \sum_{j=J+1}^\infty 2^{1-j}\\
     &= \frac\eps 2 + \frac \eps 2\\
     &= \eps
\end{align*}
So $d(x_n, x) \to 0$.